# React update properties of nested object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I have the following data:

```
      stockData: [
            {
                "ticker": "AAPL",
                "name": "Apple Inc",
                "priceChanges": {
                    "daily": 0.0155,
                    "weekly": -0.0355,
                    "monthly": -0.2000
                },
                "financialData": {   
                    "roa": 0.0574,
                    "roe": 0.2007,
                    "market_cap": "1.2T"
                }
            },
            {
                "ticker": "MSFT",
                "name": "Microsoft Corporation",
                "priceChanges": {
                    "daily": 0.0435,
                    "weekly": 0.0125,
                    "monthly": -0.2205
                },
                "financialData": {   
                    "roa": 0.0873,
                    "roe": 0.1507,
                    "market_cap": "1.3T"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I have made an API call to get this data into my React app:

```
      class MyComponent extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                stockData: [],
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/stocks")
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({

                        stockData: response.data

                    })
                })
        }

 }
```

Now my problem is that I have to convert all these NUMERIC property values (stockData.priceChanges.daily, stockData.financialData.roa etc) to percentages, which means I have to multiply them by 100 so that I could later display them correctly in a table and use the modified array in different functions.
As the properties in my array, which I have to modify, are nested, I am not really sure how to resolve this issue.

If the values were not nested, I would try to approach it like that:

```
const convertedArray = this.state.stockData.map((item) => ({

            ...item,
            daily: item.daily * 100,
            monthly: monthly.daily * 100 // and so on with other properties

        }))
```

Comment: Surely you are accessing the "nested" properties in your render function, can you not multiply by 100 there?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I would like to use the modified array in different functions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the values where you will be showing in Table or in some components but if you want to update data to have percentages instaed of values you can simply use forEach or map() to update the data

Let say you got this data from api

```js
const data = [
    {
        "ticker": "AAPL",
        "name": "Apple Inc",
        "priceChanges": {
            "daily": 0.0155,
            "weekly": -0.0355,
            "monthly": -0.2000
        },
        "financialData": {   
            "roa": 0.0574,
            "roe": 0.2007
        }
    },
    {
        "ticker": "MSFT",
        "name": "Microsoft Corporation",
        "priceChanges": {
            "daily": 0.0435,
            "weekly": 0.0125,
            "monthly": -0.2205
        },
        "financialData": {   
            "roa": 0.0873,
            "roe": 0.1507
        }
    }
];
    
    
const stock = data.map(d => {
  const priceChanges = {
    "daily": d.priceChanges.daily * 100,
    "weekly": d.priceChanges.weekly * 100,
    "monthly": d.priceChanges.monthly * 100
  };
  const financialData = {   
      "roa": d.financialData.roa * 100,
      "roe": d.financialData.roa * 100
  };
  return {
    ...d,
    priceChanges,
    financialData
  }
});

console.log(stock);
```

Comment: This is close to what I am trying to achieve. Having updated my question a bit, lets say I dont want to update all the values (I added market_cap field as well which is a string). I think that your solution works if i wanted to overwrite every property in priceChanges and financialData. If I had a lot of different properties, it would mean that I had to rewrite them all even if I didnt want to update every single one of them.

Comment: No, you only need to override values which you want to other values can be retieved as it is using `{ ...d.financialData, "roa": d.financialData.roa * 100, // so on }`

Answer (score 0):

If every nested object will be converted to percentage then use this:

```
a.map(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(_key => {
                obj[key][_key] = obj[key][_key] * 100
            });
        }
    });
return obj
});
```